# applying a function recursively on dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

`df1`:

```
    Fruit     basket1   basket2   basket3   basket4  basket5
    Fruit1    10        9         3         5        1
    Fruit2    10        10        3        10        1
    Fruit3    1         10        10       1         10
    Fruit4    1         1         1        1         1
    Fruit5    2         2         3        3         3
```

`df2`:

```
    Fruit     basket1   basket2   basket3   basket4  basket5
    Fruit1    1         0         3         4        1
    Fruit2    9         10        3         1        1
    Fruit3    10        10        10        10       10
    Fruit4    1         10        1         1        1
    Fruit5    2         20        3         3        3
```

I want to save each row of the df1 and df2 as two vectors and set up a wilcoxon test. Right now I can do it manually, row by row

```
a = as.numeric(as.vector(df1[1,]))
b = as.numeric(as.vector(df2[1,]))
wilcox.test(a,b)

a = as.numeric(as.vector(df1[2,]))
b = as.numeric(as.vector(df2[2,]))
wilcox.test(a,b)
```

and so on ...

Can you help me to do it for every row and generate a table, `df_result`.

```
Fruit   p_value
Fruit1   ...
Fruit2   ...
```

Comment: First split the data.frames into lists row-wise and use `mapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df3` is the final output.

```
# Design a function
wilcomx_p <- function(i){
  a <- as.numeric(as.vector(df1[i, -1]))
  b <- as.numeric(as.vector(df2[i, -1]))
  result <- wilcox.test(a,b)
  return(result$p.value)
}

# Apply the function, store the results to a new data frame
df3 <- df1[, 1, drop = FALSE]
df3$p_value <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), wilcomx_p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply`...

```
wilk.p <- sapply(1:nrow(df1),function(i) 
                      wilcox.test(as.numeric(df1[i,-1]),
                                  as.numeric(df2[i,-1]))$p.value)
```

This produces a vector of p-values of the wilcox test for each row.  You can easily create the df you require by

```
df_result <- data.frame(Fruit=df1$Fruit, p_value=wilk.p)

df_result
   Fruit   p_value
1 Fruit1 0.1116118
2 Fruit2 0.3808365
3 Fruit3 0.1770160
4 Fruit4 0.4237108
5 Fruit5 0.4027837
```

It will only work if the Fruits are in the same order in your two dataframes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map`. I have put everything in the same command. However, the idea is to remove the first character column from both dataframe and turn it into rownames, transpose the resulting dataframe, and convert the transposed object to dataframe again which will be recognized as a list by the `Map` command.

```
Results = Map(f = wilcox.test,
              data.frame(t(data.frame(df1[,-1], row.names = df1[,1]))),
              data.frame(t(data.frame(df2[,-1], row.names = df2[,1]))))
```